# Is it possible to restream an internet radio using PHP? (PHP guru needed)

Tags: php, apache, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

**Is it possible to restream an internet radio using PHP?**

Radio is available at port 8000. I would like to use my webserver and "transmit" the radio stream to port 80.

Is it possible?

I have already been googling it around and I found http://support.spacialnet.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=16858&start=15 <strike>but it doesn't work for me.</strike> *It does actually work. Before I just forget to change **MIME type** of the stream.*

I customized solution from previously mentioned URL (http://support.spacialnet.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=16858&start=15). It does work now, but the stream always breaks after in about 8 minutes of listening. Any clue why? 
(server max. execution time is set to 30 seconds). I tested different streams with various bitrates, but it behaves exactly same every time. Any help?

Comment: Do you have permission from the original streamer?

Comment: You may actually be breaking the law by doing this, if they're playing copywritten music or any material that requires royalties to be paid. Even if they have the right to broadcast it (e.g. due to paying royalties), you might not.

Comment: I will definitely find out if I need a permission. But anyway this would be a second step. First step is to find out if it is _technically possible_. In fact, I think permission wouldn't be nya problem, because I don't want to restream any commercial radio, it would be a statutory/public one. But thank you for a comment.

Comment: This is really a networking issue not a programming one. You should be looking at something simple like netcat.

Comment: How is this not a programming issue? He's asking about source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably shouldn't be answering this question, but I had some free time at work and wanted to play with sockets a bit.

Here is my class, it isn't well-tested(well, it worked on the first run which is suspicious) and may be buggy, but it may give you some usefull ideas. It strips ICY* headers as that example you posted, but that can be easily changed.

I tested it on Ubuntu Totem player and it played well for 10 minutes before I stopped it, but maybe I just got lucky (: At least 8 minutes seems not to be some magical number.

```
<?php

ob_start();

class RadioProxy {
    CONST STREAM_content_type='audio/aac';
    CONST STREAM_timeout=1.5;

    CONST HTTP_response_header_first='/\s200\s/';
    CONST HTTP_response_header_pattern='/^[a-z\-]+:/i';
    CONST HTTP_max_line_length=1024;

    CONST HTTP_delim="\r\n";
    CONST HTTP_max_response_headers=40;
    CONST ERROR_max=5;
    CONST ERROR_interval=120;
    CONST ERROR_usleep=300000;


    private $server_name, $server_port;
    private $HTTP_headers;
    private $STREAM = NULL;
    private $STREAM_errors = array();
    private $TIMEOUT_seconds, $TIMEOUT_microseconds;

    public function __construct($server_name, $server_port, $filename='') {
        self::STREAM_set_headers();
        $this->server_name = $server_name;
        $this->server_port = $server_port;
        $this->HTTP_headers = $this->HTTP_generate_headers($filename);
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        $HTTP_headers_length = strlen($this->HTTP_headers);
        do {

            if (!$this->STREAM_connect()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!$this->STREAM_send_headers()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!$this->STREAM_skip_headers()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!$this->STREAM_proxy()) {
                continue;
            }
        } while ($this->ERROR_is_accepteble());
    }

    private function HTTP_generate_headers($filename) {
        $header = '';
        self::HTTP_add_header($header, 'GET /' . rawurlencode($filename) . ' HTTP/1.0');
        self::HTTP_add_header($header, 'Host: ' . $this->server_name);
        self::HTTP_add_header($header, 'User-Agent: WinampMPEG/5.11');
        self::HTTP_add_header($header, 'Accept: */*');
        self::HTTP_add_header($header, 'Connection: close');
        //End of headers
        self::HTTP_add_header($header);
        return $header;
    }

    private static function HTTP_add_header(&$header, $new_header_line='') {
        $header.=$new_header_line . self::HTTP_delim;
    }

    private function ERROR_is_accepteble() {
        //Delete old errors
        array_filter($this->STREAM_errors, 'self::ERROR_remove_old');
        $this->STREAM_errors[] = time();
        usleep(self::ERROR_usleep);
        return count($this->STREAM_errors) <= self::ERROR_max;
    }

    private static function ERROR_remove_old($error_time) {
        return ($error_time - time()) <= self::ERROR_interval;
    }

    private function STREAM_connect() {
        if (!ob_get_level()) {
            ob_start();
        }
        ob_clean();
        if ($this->STREAM !== NULL) {
            fclose($this->STREAM);
        }
        $this->STREAM = fsockopen($this->server_name, $this->server_port);

        if ($this->STREAM === FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->TIMEOUT_seconds = floor(self::STREAM_timeout);
        $this->TIMEOUT_microseconds = ceil((self::STREAM_timeout - $this->TIMEOUT_seconds) * 1000);
        return stream_set_timeout($this->STREAM, $this->TIMEOUT_seconds, $this->TIMEOUT_microseconds);
    }

    private function STREAM_send_headers() {
        return fwrite($this->STREAM, $this->HTTP_headers) === strlen($this->HTTP_headers);
    }

    private function STREAM_skip_headers() {
        $read_expect = array($this->STREAM);

        $if_first_header = true;
        $header_lines_count = 0;

        do {
            stream_select($read_expect, $NULL, $NULL, $this->TIMEOUT_seconds, $this->TIMEOUT_microseconds);

            $header_line = stream_get_line($this->STREAM, self::HTTP_max_line_length, self::HTTP_delim);

            if ($header_line === FALSE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            if ($if_first_header) {
                $if_first_header = false;

                if (!preg_match(self::HTTP_response_header_first, $header_line)) {
                    return FALSE;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (empty($header_line)) {
                return TRUE;
            }

            if (!preg_match(self::HTTP_response_header_pattern, $header_line)) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $header_lines_count++;
        } while ($header_lines_count < self::HTTP_max_response_headers);

        return FALSE;
    }

    private function STREAM_proxy() {
        $read_expect = array($this->STREAM);

        //No output buffering should be here!
        while (@ob_end_clean ());

        do {
            stream_select($read_expect, $NULL, $NULL, $this->TIMEOUT_seconds, $this->TIMEOUT_microseconds);
        } while (fpassthru($this->STREAM));
    }

    private static function STREAM_set_headers() {
        //Clean all output
        ob_clean();
        header("Content-type: " . self::STREAM_content_type);
        ob_flush();
    }

}

$TestRadio = new RadioProxy('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', XXXX,'XXXX.mp3');
```

P.S. Don't do this.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will inspect it later. Why you guys keep saying I shouldn't do this? Is it a bad practice, is it dangerous, is it a legal problem or what is the real problem?? It may seems like a stupid question but I really don't get it. Thanks

Comment: Well, besides legal problems your question seems to be a very simple netwoking problem(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) or/and url rewriting problem and solving it with PHP is a very bad practice.

Comment: @tomexx What exactly doesn't work? It doesn't work at all, or do you still have that 8 minutes limit? Did you change MIME type of the stream to one that worked for you? I need more information to help you better: your OS type/version, what programm you use to test this stream, your PHP/Web server version, what stream you are trying to retransmit, etc. I tested with 119.59.98.4 port 8050 stream/Ubuntu 11.04/PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.6 with Suhosin-Patch/Apache 2.2.16 (Ubuntu)/Totem player.

Comment: @tomexx, If you can test this now, I think it would be more productive to continue this discussion in some chat(SO built-in chat/gmail/ICQ/Skype/?).

Comment: Opening file instead of plain IP address doesn't work for me. Try this one http://62.168.92.250:8000/FM_32.mp3 ... But anyway, great work!

Comment: @tomexx, Sorry about that. As I said this was just a general direction you can go with your application, not bulletproof solution. That solution you posted did lead me to think that HTTP server that streams music can answer with headers only described there (icy* and content-type*), but actually it appears that it can send back any HTTP header(server, cache-control etc.). I fixed this with creating softer regexp checks, but if you will have any problems, you can just disable checks for received headers ("preg_match(self::HTTP_response_header_*, $header_line)") or read RFC about radio streams.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. Now it works like a charm on my localhost using default EasyPHP properties. However, my live webserver has probably different setup... But this is more for built-in chat, if you have time...

Comment: @tomexx, I don't mind helping you more, but you must understand that I will do it during free time at work, so if something comes up I may be unavaliable for quite some time. As I said before, I think we should move this discussion to some kind of chat/email to make it more productive (I'm avaliable mostly during 11am-8pm GMT +3).

Answer (score 2):

I shouldn't be telling you this. But from a purely academic stand-point you probably want to be using [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php). This will allow you to load a file (in this case a stream) and dump it out immediately and for as long as it takes. (For a stream, that's forever.)

As to the particular details, that will probably look a lot like the link you provided.

Possible Issue: The maximum run-time of the script may become an issue. I'm not sure. If so, you can always increase it to something you are unlikely to reach in a given listening.

Lastly. Don't do this...

Comment: Why is it a problem? Anyway I definitely don't want to increase maximum run-time. I don't want to break something. I am just experimenting, so don't hate me :)

Comment: Try it without increasing the max run time. I'm fairly sure it doesn't need it, because we use this for large videos in our CMS and there is a very short time limit there.

Comment: I customized solution from previously mentioned url (http://support.spacialnet.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=16858&start=15). It is working now, but the stream always breaks after in about 8 minutes of listening. Any clue why? (max. execution time is set to 30 seconds)

Comment: Unsure. Could be something on either end that is interrupting the connection.

Comment: I tested it on different machines and different internet connection, I even tested different bitrates of the radio stream (128kb/s and 32kb/s) but the issue is still the same...

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely technically possible. I'd try using wireshark to look at the packets. There might be something missing at the 8 minute mark that is proprietary to SHOUTcast.

You might also try buffering it a bit. Maybe the stream stalls?

Answer (score 0):

From a logical standpoint no law can be broken here. An assumption would need be made that one person is listening to one device and that is just not knowable.

We know in homes that multiple people can be watching the same device.

Also multiple devices can be streaming a station in one location but that doesn't equate to the number of listeners. There might be 100 devices and 1 person physically listening to any of them.